# Show original price and discounted price?

Tags: commerce

I'm using this module: [Commerce Discount](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_discount) to create products discounts. In the products list view I'd like to show both prices: the original price and price with the discount. How can I do this?

I found this module:   https://drupal.org/project/commerce_price_savings_formatter but it doesn't seem to work with the [Commerce Discount](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_discount) module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work with the discount module. In fact the moudle was built with that one in mind. Install Commerce Price Savings Formatter and go to your product types's display settings and change it as per the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: What you suggest was the firt I tried. I selected the option shown in your capture, but it didn't work (the price was not visible).  Keep in mind that the Commerce Discount is not the only module that provides price discounts.

Comment: Just be sure: Did you created the discount at admin/commerce/store/discounts?

Comment: You were right. I just try it again and it works. Thanks

Comment: I am aware that this is not the only module that does discounts. I am not an idiot. However it was used as the primary source when developing the savings formatter. Anything that affects the price via rules is refelected in the savings formatted.